# n highest value per row

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with of the following structure

**Input**

```
set.seed(5)    
df <- data.frame(A= round(runif(6,0,100)),B= round(runif(6,0,100)),C= round(runif(6,0,100)),D= round(runif(6,0,100)))

   A  B  C  D
1 20 53 32 55
2 69 81 56 84
3 92 96 26 89
4 28 11 20 72
5 10 27 39 21
6 70 49 89 23
```

Now, I want to add two additional columns, each with the second and third largest element of a row, respectively.

**Output**

```
   A  B  C  D thirdLarge  secLarge
1 20 53 32 55       32         53
2 69 81 56 84       69         81
3 92 96 26 89       89         92
4 28 11 20 72       20         28
5 10 27 39 21       21         27
6 70 49 89 23       49         70
```

I tried doing it by a simple "for loop" but this is not efficient enough and takes forever with 700000 rows.

Comment: when possible, avoid using "for" loops in R. They are not very efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `apply` :

```
df[c('thirdLarge', 'secLarge')] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) 
                sort(x)[c(length(x)-2, length(x) - 1)]))
#This is shorter
df[c('thirdLarge', 'secLarge')] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) 
                        sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[3:2]))

df
#   A  B  C  D thirdLarge secLarge
#1 20 53 32 55         32       53
#2 69 81 56 84         69       81
#3 92 96 26 89         89       92
#4 28 11 20 72         20       28
#5 10 27 39 21         21       27
#6 70 49 89 23         49       70
```

Using `rank` as suggested by @Chris Ruehlemann but this will fail if you two same value in a row.

```
df[c('secLarge', 'thirdLarge')] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) 
                                      x[rank(-x) %in% 2:3]))
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I always shied away from learning `apply`. I really should change that. crazy how much more efficient that is.

Comment: A beautiful solution. Been playing around with `rank`, which to my mind should also go some way toward a solution. Any idea how that would be used?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out why the same code does not work if the goal is to just create a single new column, say, for the 4th largest value per row: `df["fourthLarge"] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[rank(-x) %in% 4]))
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "fourthLarge", value = c(20, 56, 26,  : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 6`. Neither `%in%`nor `==`works. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: You don't need transpose in that case. `df$fourthLarge <- apply(df, 1, function(x) x[rank(-x) == 4])`

Answer (score 3):

If speed is an issue, check out the **Rfast** package:

```
library(Rfast)
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, 
       lrg.2 = rownth(as.matrix(df), elems=rep(2, nrow(df)), descending=TRUE),
       lrg.3 = rownth(as.matrix(df), elems=rep(3, nrow(df)), descending=TRUE))

   A  B  C  D lrg.2 lrg.3
1 20 53 32 55    53    32
2 69 81 56 84    81    69
3 92 96 26 89    92    89
4 28 11 20 72    28    20
5 10 27 39 21    27    21
6 70 49 89 23    70    49
```

For a data frame containing 700,000 rows, this takes <1 second. Using apply takes >30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing if I could make a much faster base version that didn't need `apply`:

Essentially I order once by `row` and decreasing value, then feed it back into a `matrix` and take the required columns:

```
udf <- unlist(df)
mat <- matrix(udf[order(row(df), -udf)], ncol=ncol(df), byrow=TRUE)
df[c('thirdLarge','secLarge')] <- mat[,3:2]

##   A  B  C  D thirdLarge secLarge
##1 20 53 32 55         32       53
##2 69 81 56 84         69       81
##3 92 96 26 89         89       92
##4 28 11 20 72         20       28
##5 10 27 39 21         21       27
##6 70 49 89 23         49       70

df <- df[rep(1:6, 116667),]
## 700,002 rows

system.time({
    udf <- unlist(df)
    mat <- matrix(udf[order(row(df), -udf)], ncol=ncol(df), byrow=TRUE)
    df[c('thirdLarge','secLarge')] <- mat[,3:2]
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##  0.971   0.000   0.972
```

Comparing looping over rows with `apply`:

```
system.time({
    df[c('thirdLarge', 'secLarge')] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) 
                        sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[3:2]))
})
##   user  system elapsed 
## 24.362   0.003  24.365
```